# Codeception actor not found exception

Tags: php, codeception

When running `codecept run -vvv` I get an error stating that the actor is undefined in the SuiteManager class (method is initialize).
Any guess on how to fix this?

I've set up two basic unit tests where I just want to assert some values, and they worked until I switched to the composer autoloader.

[image: Error log]

In the composer.json I have the following:

`"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "app"
    ]
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^2.3",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.8.0",
    "symfony/console": "^3.3"
  }`

In the main _bootstrap file provided by Codeception I only have a require_once for the vendor autoloader file.
Using php 7.1 and latest versions of the packages.

Comment: Have you tried a `composer dumpautoload -o`?

Comment: @milz just tried it, also doing composer to check for any updates and still the same error.
How would you autoload your classes?

Comment: Actually, after looking closely to the screenshot, PHP isn't telling you the class `Actor` is not found. It's telling you that somewhere you have an array with `actor` as the key and that key doesn't exist. Please post the code of your tests.

Comment: If you look at the trace, you can see it's calling SuiteManager->initialize(). This is from phpunit, standard code.
In my tests (which are basically oneliners) I don't do anything with arrays.
Example: $this->tester->assertTrue(View::exists('index'));

Comment: Try running `codecept build`. It seems the issue is related to the settings, but I can't replicate the issue. If the command doesn't work please add the relevant source files on the question so I can replicate the issue.

Comment: This is what I get when I try doing codecept build:

http://i.imgur.com/k7NFvnW.png


_bootstrap.php in _support 

http://i.imgur.com/V5xTipj.png


One of my tests:

http://i.imgur.com/MRhbzAG.png

Comment: Look at your screenshot, you are running your tests with Codeception 2.1.11,  Probably you have a globally installed version. Run a local version with `./vendor/bin/codecept`

Comment: Wow, never realised that... Will try it when I get home and report the results here!

Comment: It indeed worked, but now somehow the output is completely broken. It outputs large amounts of whitespace and even phpdocs. It also crashes my cli :/
(I did not change anything to my code and even tried to reinstall codeception)